# Rake route Error "Missing :action key on routes definition"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am getting

```
$ rake routes
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: Missing :action key on routes definition, please check your routes.
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:243:in `default_controller_and_action'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:117:in `normalize_options!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:65:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1487:in `new'
/usr/local/r................
```

Here is my Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'script/index'

  get 'landing/index'

  root 'landing/index'
end
```

What is causing the problem and how do I fix it.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

[The Rails router recognizes URLs and dispatches them to a controller's action.](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) The error is caused by missing out the mapped action.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  #   url               action
  get 'script/index' => 'script#index'
  get 'landing/index' => 'landing#index'
  root 'script#index'
end
```

Comment: Basically your defining both how the root will look (left) and how rails will actually find it (right).

Comment: Important: Use **#** symbol at the **right** side. (This was the error reason in my case.)

Answer (score 13):

You can do it many ways, these all work:

- get 'script/index'
- get 'script/index' => 'script#index'
- get 'script/index', to: 'script#index'

Think of **path** first and **controller#method** to follow.

Root is a special case, always: **root 'script#index'**

Answer (score 6):

Change
`root 'landing/index'`
to
`root 'landing#index'`

Comment: 9 years programming in rails and somehow I missed this lol, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error running `rails g`.

**If you run a command that uses `routes.rb`, the file needs to be error free for the command to work.**

In your case, you had paths, but you didn't match them to actions, so the `routes.rb` file was broken. You needed something like `get 'landing/index' => 'my_controller#my_action'`

Answer (score 0):

**Kaleidoscope**'s code works just fine. Below is a slightly concise version.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'script/index'
  get 'landing/index'
  root 'script#index'
end
```

Rails add the left side of the arrow(=>) by convention replacing `/` with `#`.